# Why is $\mathbb{E}\left(Z|X\right)$ a "fair" estimate for $Z$?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, conditional-expectation, estimation, parameter-estimation

> In statistics, a natural initial estimate for a random variable $Z$, is its conditional mean with some given random variable $X$ that is, $\mathbb{E}\left(Z|X\right)$.

With regard to why this is a "good enough" estimate, I am not sure what to make of the following- whether it is complete or even correct:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left(Z|X\right)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left(Z\right)$$
This is equivalent to saying that $\mathbb{E}\left(Z|X\right)$ is an unbiased estimate of $\mathbb{E}\left(Z\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation). It is correct (provided $\Bbb E(Z)$ is defined).

Comment: Does this also justify why $E(Z|X)$ may be used as an estimate for $Z$?

Comment: Without context, it's hard to say. Certainly depends on what you can make out of $X$. If $X$ is constant, for instance, then all you're getting is $\Bbb E(Z)$.